# How to make a private attribute/method in Dojo?

Tags: javascript, scope, dojo, private

I have a custom class/widget defined in dojo. How do I make some of its attributes/methods private?

The Dojo documentation advocates the use of _underscore to mark an attribute/method as private, but this seems to be just a convention and doesn't really make the attribute/method private.

```
define(
    ["dojo/_base/declare"],
    function(declare) {
        declare("MyWidget", [_WidgetBase], {
            publicAttr: 8,
            publicMethod: function() { ... },
            _privateAttr: 7,
            _privateMethod: function() { ... }
        });
    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

Usually while developing in JavaScript, developers like to prefix their private members with an underscore to let other developers know not to touch them. It's just a convention and not really private.

In JavaScript, it's really easy to make variables and functions private (local variables and functions). Unfortunately, it’s not possible to make properties of objects private.

If you really don't want a function/variable not be accessible from the Object you could implement something like below.

```
define(["dojo/_base/declare"], function(declare) {

    function privateFunction(obj){
        //do something private
    }

    declare("MyWidget", [_WidgetBase], {
        publicAttr: 8,
        publicMethod: function() {
            privateFuntion(this);
        },
    });
});
```

Here the function `privateFunction` is accessible to the widget's mehtods and others will not be able to call the function through the instance of the widget.

You could make the context of the function to widget, then you will be able to access all the properties of the widget through `this` and no need to pass the widget instance as parameter. There are couple of way you can achieve it. You could you `lang.hitch`. My favorite is

```
privateFunction.call(this, args..);
```

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: I think dojo use underscore naming convention to specify private variables.

Comment: Yes, and private functions too.